# C++ vector with managed objects

Tags: c++, managed

Hello I need to have vector (or some other data structure, which is similar) filled with managed objects.

Usually I can write:

```
std::vector<Object> vect;
```

But I cannot use:

```
std::vector<Object^> vect;
```

Can somebody explain, how to change declaration or advice other structure instead of vector. Thanks.

Comment: What is your intention behind this? Are you using C++/CLI? Or rather WinRT?

Comment: Use .NET generic List class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Comment: @AlexFarber this is about C++, not C#.

Comment: @bash.d: No. This is about C++.Net, in which `List` might indeed be the correct answer.

Comment: @ereOn this might be, but how do you know? Nothing has been said about this...

Comment: @bash.d: One would think that the `Object^` and the `C++`,`managed` tags kind of imply that. :)

Comment: @ereOn The "hat"-notation (^) also exists in Windows 8 /XAML, which is a little different from C++/CLI.

Comment: @bash.d: ...which aren't C++ either, invalidating your own previous statement. Where do you want to go with that ?

Comment: Nonsense! There is no std-namespace in .NET. Whereas it does exist in WinRT.

Comment: Thank you for advice, everything works, I used this: "List<MyObject^>^ listName"

Comment: @AlexFarber: You may want to post that as an answer, especially since it has been proven to be the right answer.

Comment: I have one more question about this. How to iterate through this list? I have it in some class and I need method witch returns one value from list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use .NET generic List class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

List enumeration sample from the same WEB page, as requested by user1237747's comment:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    List<String^>^ dinosaurs = gcnew List<String^>();

    dinosaurs->Add("Tyrannosaurus");
    dinosaurs->Add("Amargasaurus");

    for each(String^ dinosaur in dinosaurs )
    {
        Console::WriteLine(dinosaur);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Replace String^ with the type you need. You can also access List elements by index using [] operator.

Generally, avoid mixing managed and unmanaged types, if this is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: Can the type be a value class? If yes, can the List be declared as `List <MyValueClass ^>^ myList;`?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are stl data structures for managed types.  Below is an example using a vector (per your request).

```
#include <cliext/vector>

cliext::vector<Object^> vect;
```

Docs for this vector type are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386284.aspx)

Comment: This did not work for me: The decalration yields "Error C2833 'operator _Mycont_it' is not a recognized operator or type".